# Failed to mount component: template or render function not defined?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, webpack, vue.js

I am creating website using node.js, express, pug, vue.js. I have one problem regarding Vue.js

app.js

```
window.Vue = require('vue');
Vue.component('work-list', require('../views/components/WorkList.vue'));

const app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    message: 'Welcome'
  }
});
```

WorkList.vue

```
<script>
  export default {
    name: 'WorkList',
    data: function () {
      return {
        message: 'WorkList Page'
      }
    }
  }
</script>
```

index.pug

```
(HTML Code..)
body
    #app.container
        h1 {{ message}}
        .row
            block content
        a(href="/worklist") Go to worklist
  script(src="bundle.js")
```

worklist.pug

```
extends index.pug

block content
work-list {{ message }}
```

When I try to access worklist page, browser is returning following error message.

[image]

How can I make WorkList in Root element?

Comment: my code url: https://github.com/ofleaf/webview

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your component file 'WorkList.vue' needs a template defined.  The most straight forward way to construct a '.vue' component is with three sections.

```
<template>
   //template code goes here.
</template>

<script>
   // vue javascript here
</script>

<style>
   // applicable styles here
</style>
```

Your component is expecting the `<template>` markup.

There are other ways to define the template as well. https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/render-function.html

**When defining your component**

```
Vue.component('my-component', {
    template: `<div> markup here</div>`,
    data(){
      ...
    }
});
```

**X-Templates (similar to above)**

```
Vue.component('my-component', {
    template: `#someElementId`,
    ....

 //then in a separate component.js file

 <script type="text/x-template" id="someElementId">
   <div> markup here </div>
</script>
```

**Using the render function**

```
export default {
    data() {
     ...
    }
    render(createElement) {
        return createElement(
            'div', {....}
        ....
```

Comment: I tried Vue.component('work-list', { template: (...) }); it works. But <template>...</template><script>...</script> in WorkList.vue doesn't work. Returned same error. WorkList element out of Root element.

Comment: Are you building your `.vue` component using webpack?  I have never used Pug  as a pre-processor so it may be a problem there?

Comment: I changed app.js file. Using import WorkList from '...'; and component to register app. It works. Thanks for reply.

Answer (score 8):

This might also occur even when a `<template></template>` *is* defined in your Vue single file component.  In addition to `require('/path/to/your/Component.vue')` as the second parameter to `Vue.component()` when registering the component globally in your app.js, you also have to specify `.default`:

```js
Vue.component('work-list', require('../views/components/WorkList.vue').default);
                                                                      ^^^^^^^^
```

Comment: This must have changed from an older Vue version.  I dusted off a project after a few months and this fixed this issue.

Comment: I would give you more than 1 upvote if I could, thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Following on from [Erich's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57977903/799588), if you are using ES6 imports it would be:

```
import WorkList from '../views/components/WorkList'; // .vue is extension not required

Vue.component('work-list', WorkList);
```

Answer (score 2):

In my case, I forgot to put my dynamic import inside an arrow function.

Wrong:

```
{
    path: "/example/",
    component: import("@/pages/Example"),
}
```

Correct:

```
{
    path: "/example/",
    component: () => import("@/pages/Example"),
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe the problem is the alias for `vue` in your webpack config.

Check out the different types of [Vue builds](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/installation.html#Explanation-of-Different-Builds).

Try using `vue.min.js` or `vue.common.js`

```
//webpack.config.js
...
alias: {
  'vue$': 'vue/dist/vue.common.js'
},
...
```